# React Query setQueryData appends value to an array twice in Socket.io listener

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-query

I am building a messenger and I am using React Query for server-side state management. When receiving a new message I manually update query data using setQueryData, however the message gets added to messages array twice. My guess is it has something to do with React Strict mode, however I am unable to understand how to fix this.

```
socket.on("newMessage", (msg) => {
 queryClient.setQueryData(
   ["chats", msg.chat],
   (oldChat) => {
      return { ...oldChat, messages: oldChat.messages.concat(msg) };
   }
 );
});
```

If the chat message array looks like this before the new message:

```
[messageA, messageB]
```

Adding messageC results in:

```
[messageA, messageB, messageC, messageC]
```

This is a frontend issue, since the message is added to the database once, and after refetching chat messages there is only one instance of messageC.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it. The issue was with `socket.on("newMessage", callback)` listener being registered twice, thus triggering the setQueryData two times separately. To solve this I have moved the listener initialization to a useEffect hook, with cleanup functions for socket listeners.